# SSRS won't allow parameters in embedded dataset based on data source

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Whenever I construct a report that uses an embedded dataset and try to use a parameter (such as @StartDate and @EndDate), I receive an error that states I must declare scalar values. However, this error only comes up if I set a data source that uses the "credentials stored securely in the report server" option. If I set the data source to use "Windows integrated security," I do not receive the error.

I am at a complete loss. These reports need to be accessed by a large amount of people. We have granted them "browser" privileges through an Active Directory Group through SSRS, including the data sources.

What is the best way to proceed? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 0):

I generally deploy with the option already set by going into the Data Source and choosing 'Log on to SQL Server' section > 'Use SQL Server Authentication'> (Set your user and settings).  When you use a windows user as your main user after you deploy there could be issues.

The other question would be does this work correctly at all times in Business Intelligence Development Studio, BIDS, and just not on the server?  It is very interesting a permission issue alone would cause a scalar error to return.  Generally when users have to get to the report they may still get the error but not storing the credentials merely asks them for credentials.  It would help more to know the datasets and what they are returning or supposed to be returning.  Generally a Start and End are typically defined as 'DataTime' in SSRS and are in a predicate like 'Where thing between @Start and @End' and there data is chosen from a calendar by a user.  If you are binding them to other datasets and there is the possibility of a user selecting multiple values that could present an issue.

Comment: Actually, I took a look at the data source that had been set up by our DBA. It was set up as an ODBC connection. I changed it to Microsoft SQL. It works now (???)

Comment: I wish I could give you a more detailed answer on behavior of ODBC to SQL connection but I cannot.  In my experience I always use SQL Server when I KNOW I will only use a SQL Server for my data.  I could only guess that it could potentially be something the way your dataset is determined.  Is it a temp table or table variable or query from permanent tables?  All kinds of factors of the language if you are using TSQL statements could be affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the data source that had been set up by our DBA. It was set up as an ODBC connection. I changed it to Microsoft SQL. It works now. I do not understand why and would appreciate if a more seasoned individual might explain.